# how to create an Edit Task on local database samples?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was developing Windows Phone App using this sample: [Local Database Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Local-Database-Sample-57b1614c)

In that sample, There will be no Edit Task has been implemented. So, I decided to implement Edit Task. But, it does not works for me.

If I pressed `Edit`, app breaks.

I dunno what mistake I have done.

**C# Code:**

```
    private void editTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(
        new Uri(string.Format("/NewTaskPage.xaml?Id={0}", (allToDoItemsListBox.SelectedItem as ToDoItem).ToDoItemId), UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: can you state what actual error message you get when the app breaks? Without this no one is able to help you, looking at your code, (allToDoItemsListBox.SelectedItem as ToDoItem) could return null so that trying to reference the ToDoItemId will throw a null exception, for all we know the exception could be thrown in the NewTaskPage.xaml page as well. In other words, provide more context. Debug your code and post the exception that is being thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go thorough bellow link here is example of local daabase in windows phone 8 with sqlite.

[Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

[SQLite-WinRT: Database programming on Windows Phone and Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

[How to use SQLite in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Hope it will help you

Comment: @Csharp_Newbie: if you got solution from my answer than plz up vote it